Coherent states on compact abelian state spaces and complexification
First, to establish notation, let $T^*(M)$ denote the cotangent bundle of a manifold $M$.  Let $\widehat{(-)}:= \hom_{\sf LCAbGrp}(-,\mathbb{T}):{\sf LCAbGrp}^{\sf op}\simeq {\sf LCAbGrp}$ denote the Pontryagin dual functor into the circle $\mathbb T$, where $\sf LCAbGrp$ is the category of locally compact Abelian groups and continuous group homorphisms. Given a Lie group $G$, let $G_{\mathbb C}$ denote its universal complexification.
The motivation for this question comes from coherent states of the quantum harmonic oscilator. Squeezed coherent states for $n$ quantum Harmonic oscillators are certain bounded states on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$; moreover, Gaussian unitaries are bounded automorphisms on the same Hilbert space.
Up to global phase, Gaussian unitaries are faithfully represented by affine symplectomorphisms on the phase space (with respect to the canonical symplectic form):
$$T^*(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \widehat{\mathbb{R}^n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n} $$
Whereas, again up to global phase, squeezed coherent states/Gaussian states are in bijection with affine Lagrangian subspaces of the complexified phase space
$$
T^*(\mathbb{R}^n)_{\mathbb{C}} \cong (\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \widehat{\mathbb{R}^n })_{\mathbb{C}} \cong (\mathbb{R}^{n})_{\mathbb{C}}\times (\widehat{\mathbb{R}^n})_{\mathbb{C}} \cong \mathbb{C}^{2n}
$$
Where the complex component is required moreover to be (strictly) positive definite. The idea is that these subspaces correspond to the Gaussian probability distributions on $ \mathbb{R}^{2n} $ satisfying Heisenberg's uncertainty principle for pure states.
Given a locally compact Abelian group $G$, we can similarly construct Hilbert spaces $L^2(G) \cong L^2(\hat G)$.  Moreover, there is a faithful, projective representation of the symplectomorphisms on $G\times \hat G$ into automorphisms on $L^2(G)$   (with respect to canonical the symplectic form).
There is similarly a notion of squeezed coherent states on $L^2(G)$, which can be represented in terms of well-behaved Gaussian probability distributions on phase-space $G\times \hat G$.
My question is as follows.  If $G$ is a Lie group, can squeezed coherent states on $L^2(G)$ be identified with some class of Lagrangian subspaces of the phase space $G_{\mathbb C} \times \widehat{G_{\mathbb C}}$ as is the case for the quantum Harmonic oscillator?  If not, is there some way to represent Gaussian probability distributions on phase space, purely group theoretically?
The example I am interested in is of $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ where $\widehat{\mathbb T} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{C}}\cong \mathbb{C}^\times \cong \mathbb{T}\times \mathbb{R}$ (thanks to Loren).  Therefore, $\widehat{\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{C}}} \cong \widehat{ \mathbb{T}\times \mathbb{R}} \cong \hat{ \mathbb{T}}\times \hat{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}$.  Therefore for a single mode, I would be interested in Lagrangian subgroups of $\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{C}} \times \widehat{\mathbb{T}_{\mathbb{C}}} \cong \mathbb{T}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{R}^2$ where both real components are positive.

$\mathbb C^\times$ is $\mathbb R \times S^1$.  $\mathbb R$ is self-dual and $\widehat{S^1}$ is $\mathbb Z$.
